# Deprecated -undefined dynamic_lookup on iOS - Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I am trying to create a new app in Xcode in which I am using Firebase for the back-end. In the other apps I have made I have not yet used CocoaPods, but in order to use Firebase for this app I am required to install it via Podfile. I followed the directions from Firebase and also, everything is up to date. When I create the project, everything is fine, however after creating a workspace and launching that in Xcode I get a warning that -undefined dynamic_lookup is depreciated on iOS. Does anyone know how to resolve this warning? My podfile looks like this:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'BodyComp' do
pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'
end

target 'BodyCompTests' do

end

target 'BodyCompUITests' do

end
```

Cheers